# I am unable to read in AngularJS, as it is a lookup to user i used apex input field

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

```
   <apex:inputField id="lookup" value="{!surveyObj.User__c}" style="width: 300px;" html-placeholder="select The User from the Lookup"><br/><br/>
```

## this is the lookup to user, and i wanna get that value in AngularJs...i

in the below code i am able to get the data for input type="text"

```
<input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name"  ng-model="lastName"/>
```

so here i am using   `ng-model="lastName"` for this so i can able to get the input value.

But the above code (1st or 2nd  line) i am using `<apex:input filed......>`
so,Here i am facing the challange....could any one pls help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value by  as `html-ng-model="lastname"`:

```
<apex:inputField id="lookup" value="{!surveyObj.User__c}" style="width: 300px;" html-placeholder="select The User from the Lookup" html-ng-model="lastname">
```

Or 
As an alternate solution you can bind the apex input field by jquery on change. So, by change event just copy the value to *hidden* html input field which has `ng-model=lastname` and use it in `$scope`

Comment: html-ng-model worked for me,
Thank You So Much Rob

Comment: This gives you the text value, but not the value of the Id. How did you get the Id value? @mujeeb